# Trigger the click event of asp.net linkbutton on mouseenter using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, triggers, linkbutton

I am trying to trigger a click event on hover using jQuery.

This is pretty simple but it would seem I can not trigger the click of an asp.net linkbutton which refreshes the content of an updatepanel using this method.

Here's the code - fairly standard so not sure it will make a difference.

```
$("a.testbutton").mouseenter( function() {
    $(this).trigger('click');
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Programmatically triggering click differs from actual click. note that hover is `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

Comment: Thanks... editted question based on your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Programmatically triggering click differs from actual click event, try the following.

```
$("a.testbutton").mouseenter(function() {
    window.location.href = this.href
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$("a.testbutton").mouseenter( function() {
    $(this).click(function(alert();)) //replace alert(); with your refresh function
});
```

Comment: No difference... - plus now edited question to use mouseenter rather than hover.

Comment: hang on, does the link button actualy do somethin onclick? if not use : '$(this).click(function(){ alert() });'